# Customize icons color in fortysecond CV

Tags: color, cv, fontawesome

I'm doing my CV using this [template](https://es.overleaf.com/articles/anirban-bhattacharyas-resume/cmnzzrwvkcsw) (main.tex) and I would like to have four different colors for the "pack" of icons just below the name, the dots of the languages, the Hard and Soft skills, just like the picture below.

[image]

I found the command lines that set all the icons the same colors but I think I have to modify several things in order to have want I would like, just I can't figure out what

```
% uniform icon style for all skill icons, e.g. flags or fontawesome icons
\newcommand{\cvicon}[1]{\makebox[1em]{\color{iconcolor} #1}}
\newcommand{\flag}[1]{\includegraphics[align=c, width=1em]{#1}}
```

Plus I would like also the headers in the right part like the picture below, but still, I don't get how to do it

[image]

Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get this style

[image: c]

Add this code after `\documentclass[ a4paper ]{fortysecondscv}` and choose the colors of your liking by changing any of the six

`\definecolor{<color name>}[rgb]{0...1, 0...1, 0...1}`

```
%%**********************************************************
\definecolor{socialnetwork}{rgb}{1,0.5,1}
\definecolor{personalinner}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\definecolor{personalicon}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{softskills}{rgb}{0.8,0.3,0.2}
\definecolor{hardskills}{rgb}{0.2,0.8,0.8}
\definecolor{languages}{rgb}{0.0,0.8,0.0}

%% ************* Personal data <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand*\circleicon[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline = (char.base)]{%
        \node[%
        shape=circle,%
        inner sep=1pt,%
        fill=personalinner,% 
        text=personalicon,%
        minimum size=\hsize%
        ] (char) {#1};%
    }%
}

%*****************  social network <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand*{\socialicon}[1]{%
    \resizebox{\hsize}{!}{\textcolor{socialnetwork}{#1}}%
}

% ******************* soft skills <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand{\cvicon}[1]{\makebox[1em]{\color{softskills} #1}}

% ******************* hardskills <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\cviconx}[1]{\makebox[1em]{\color{hardskills} #1}}
\renewcommand{\skill}[3][0em]{
    \hspace{#1} \cviconx{#2} ~ \parbox{\linewidth-#1-2.5em}{#3} \hfill \par
}
%************************  languages <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,
\RenewDocumentCommand{\pointskill}{ O{0em} m m m O{5} }{%
    \hspace{#1} \cvicon{#2} ~ #3 \hfill%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#5}{%
        \space%
        {\ifnumgreater{\x}{#4}{\color{skillbg}}{\color{languages}}% 
            \raisebox{0.5\height-0.4ex}{\scriptsize\faCircle}%
        }
    }\par%
}

%*****************************************************************************************
```

**UPDATE** This is minimal code for quickly trying out new colors.

```
\documentclass[ a4paper ]{fortysecondscv}

%%********************************************* CHOOSE THE COLORS HERE<<<<<
\definecolor{socialnetwork}{rgb}{1,0.5,1}
\definecolor{personalinner}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\definecolor{personalicon}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{softskills}{rgb}{0.8,0.3,0.2}
\definecolor{hardskills}{rgb}{0.7,0.8,0.0}
\definecolor{languages}{rgb}{0.0,0.8,0.0}

%% ************* Personal data <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand*\circleicon[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline = (char.base)]{%
        \node[%
        shape=circle,%
        inner sep=1pt,%
        fill=personalinner,% 
        text=personalicon,%
        minimum size=\hsize%
        ] (char) {#1};%
    }%
}

%*****************  social network <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand*{\socialicon}[1]{%
    \resizebox{\hsize}{!}{\textcolor{socialnetwork}{#1}}%
}

% ******************* soft skills <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand{\cvicon}[1]{\makebox[1em]{\color{softskills} #1}}

% ******************* hardskills <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\cviconx}[1]{\makebox[1em]{\color{hardskills} #1}}
\renewcommand{\skill}[3][0em]{
    \hspace{#1} \cviconx{#2} ~ \parbox{\linewidth-#1-2.5em}{#3} \hfill \par
}
%************************  languages <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,
\RenewDocumentCommand{\pointskill}{ O{0em} m m m O{5} }{%
    \hspace{#1} \cvicon{#2} ~ #3 \hfill%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#5}{%
        \space%
        {\ifnumgreater{\x}{#4}{\color{skillbg}}{\color{languages}}% 
            \raisebox{0.5\height-0.4ex}{\scriptsize\faCircle}%
        }
    }\par%
}   
%*****************************************************************************************


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                            PERSONAL INFORMATION
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cvname{Test New Colors}
\cvjobtitle{}
\cvprofilepic{example-image}
\cvbirthday{\today}
\cvaddress{Park Ave.~1, 555 555 B-Woods}
% phone number
\cvphone{+86 555 555 555}
% personal website
\cvsite{https://pandascience.net}
% email address
\cvmail{panda@bamboo.cn}
% pgp key
\cvkey{4096R/FF00FF00}{0xAABBCCDDFF00FF00}
% any other custom entry
\cvcustomdata{\faFlag}{Chinese}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                              SIDEBAR 1st PAGE
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% add more profile sections to sidebar on first page
\addtofrontsidebar{
    \graphicspath{{pics/flags/}}

    \profilesection{Social Network}
        \begin{icontable}{2.5em}{1em}
            \social{\faArchive}
                {https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/forty-seconds-cv/pztcktmyngsk}
                {Overleaf Template Link}
            \social{\faGithub}
                {https://github.com/PandaScience/FortySecondsCV}
                {Github Project Page Link}
        \end{icontable}

    \profilesection{Languages}
        \pointskill{\flag{CN.png}}{Chinese}{5}
        \pointskill{\flag{DE.png}}{German}{3}
        \pointskill{\flag{GB.png}}{English}{3}
        \pointskill{\flag{FR.png}}{French}{3}

    \profilesection{Hard Skills}
        \skill{\faBalanceScale}{Sleeping almost all day}
        \skill{\faSitemap}{Eating a lot bamboo sprouts}
        \skill{\faGraduationCap}{Relaxing rest of the day}

    \profilesection{Soft Skills}
        \pointskill{\faHome}{Looking Cute}{4}[4]
        \pointskill{\faChild}{Chillin' hard}{3}[4]
}


\begin{document}

\makefrontsidebar

\end{document}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I was really struggling! I did exactly as you said and it sorts of work but the hard and soft skills still have the same color. In fact, it uses the color defined by the hardskills lines (aqua green) and I don't understand why you don't have the same issue if the code is the same :|

Comment: @Cecilia M (1) Did my answer solve your question? As you see in the picture hard skills have  a different color than soft. Try to change them using the `\definecolor{` provided. (2) You are asking why the solution works?. Please explain. (3) **Important**: To test the new code start with the original template, without any code of your own.

Comment: @Cecilia M I added as UPDATE a complete minimal compilable code to test the colors one by one.